# How to generate multiple, numeric-style citation call-outs?

Tags: citing

In my kile documents, I want to add multiple citations. For this I use the command

```
\cite{cristo,taylor,polgar,phillips,speirs,simoes,roberto}
```

The names in this command give numeric references, which is what I wanted, but not in the way I want it. It gives `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` instead of `[1,2,4-8]`. Is there any other way to manage this?
My bibliography style is `elsarticle-num`, and I use `bibtex` for the bibliography.

I use this preamble in my document:

```
\documentclass[review,preprint,twocolumn,3p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace{5mm}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your comment to Mico's answer would probably be added by a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): could you edit one into the question? You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post: I'll edit it out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

(Answer modified after the OP provided additional, crucial information about the document's setup.)

Since you're using the `elsarticle` document class, which loads the `natbib` citation management package, just issue the command

```
\biboptions{numbers,sort&compress}
```

in the preamble. This instructs `natbib` to sort and compress numeric-style citations. (Note that there seems to be a typo in the documentation of the `elsarticle` document class: The option should be spelled `numbers` rather than `number`.)

Perfect!! This command works greatly for `elsarticle`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mico. I checked that cite package already is installed under texlive. However, I got this error when multiple citations are given with the cite command: paragraph ended befor \@citex was complete ?

Comment: @RızaBayoğlu - please augment your question with some code that demonstrates what exactly you're doing. Without such information, it's going to be virtually impossible to come up with a solution. Thanks.

Comment: \documentclass[review,preprint,twocolumn,3p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace{5mm}}

Comment: I use the command in introduction part of my document in kile: \cite{cristo,taylor,polgar,phillips,speirs,simoes,roberto}. But the names in this command gives numeric refecences which is what I wanted, but not in the way I mentioned in my question. I mean it gives [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. I hope that information is adequate. @Micho

Comment: @RızaBayoğlu: I can't tell for sure from the way you've reported the contents of your document's preamble in the follow-up comment, but it would appear that the `\usepackage{cite}` as well as, possibly, a few more `\usepackage` statements are commented out, and hence that these packages aren't being loaded at all. Please consider adding this information to the *body of your original question* so that that formatting information is preserved. By the way, which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: @Micho: Sory for the bad writing. I changed my original question with regard to your suggestions.

Comment: @RızaBayoğlu: Thanks for updating/augmenting your original question. I've provided an addendum to my answer to suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: @Micho: I put the command (\biboptions...) under the packages in the preamble. Your addendum partially solved my problem. Now, it gives me what I wanted. However, when I compile the source I get this error in the natbib.sty:   http://s11.postimage.org/sdvvq7t0z/natbib.png

Comment: @RızaBayoğlu - Hmm, there seems to be a typo in the documentation for the `elsarticle` document class: the option should be spelled `numbers` and not `number`! I'm updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Micho: Thanks Mico. It solved my problem completely.

Answer (score 4):

put the command `sort&compress` in the documentclass options: `\documentclass[3p,sort&compress]{elsarticle}`

Perfect!! This command works greatly for `elsarticle`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Your "answer" would be better as a comment on Mico's answer.  All you are saying is that option can be passed to the class rather using the `\biboptions` command.