# How to make long references inside the text? Latex

Tags: citing

I'm using texmaker and I inside my text I mention a particular phenomenon. I then want to make reference to a series of papers, you know, like "... gaussian beams, [10,11]", but my list is longer than that. I wanto to write the reference as [10-14] but the best I can do is [10,11,12,13].

I'm using the command \cite{ref11, ref12, ref13, ref14}. How can I achieve this [10-14] form?

Comment: What citation packages can you use/are you using at the moment?

Comment: See, for example, [How to add multiple citation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82293/5764)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.