# Mulitple reference citation with usepackage{cite}

Tags: citing

since i want that multiple citations look like [1-5], instead of [1,2,3,4,5] i did the following thing as suggested here "http://texblog.org/2007/05/28/mulitple-reference-citation/"

I load the package \usepackage{cite}, but now i get a lot of error messages:

`Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.`

for every empty line in the editor (I do this to get a better overview).

Example:

```
@misc{A01,

author = {Jones, A. and James, C., and Giannini, J.},

year = {2001},

title = {Title of journal article},

}


\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\journal{Energy}



\begin{document}
lasjfsjlf


sjflsjdlfj \cite{A01}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

Hope someone can help me; thank you

Comment: Can you please include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) exhibiting this error?

Comment: Added an example --> perhaps \citep works?

Comment: It seems `elsarticle` is not compatible with the `cite` package. Fortunately, `elsarticle` itself [provides the functionality you want](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82293/how-to-generate-multiple-numeric-style-citation-call-outs). In your example `\citep` still works because it is provided by `elsarticle` and not `cite`, whereas `\cite` is provided by `elsarticle` and then incompatibly overwritten by `cite`.